# Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: x> on <x.x:x> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am fairly new to Swift but I am creating a app that requires after a certain time to enter either Touch-ID or a PIN. I am checking a timer from AppDelegate.swift to see if it has expired and if it has expired I am making a call to my "BaseTableViewController" which holds my function authenticateUser. Again I am calling this from my AppDelegate.swift file by creating an instance of BaseTableViewController `var baseTableVC = BaseTableViewController()` and making a call if timer expired to `self.baseTableVC.authenticateUser()`.

Anyways I am getting: Warning: `Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fed5ae1dcf0> on <admin.BaseViewController: 0x7fed5ad279d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Thank you in advance for you help!

```
    func showPasswordAlert(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Touch ID Password", message: "Please enter your password", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) {(action) -> Void in
        if let textField = alertController.textFields?.first as UITextField?{
            if textField.text == "hello" {
                print("Authentication successfull!")
            }
            else{
                self.showPasswordAlert()
            }
        }

    }
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler{(textField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Password"
        textField.secureTextEntry = true

    }
    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func authenticateUser(){
    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?
    let reasonString = "Authentication is required for Admin!"
    context.localizedFallbackTitle = "Enter your PIN Code"

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error){
        context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reasonString, reply: {(success, policyError) ->Void in
            if success{
                print("Authentication successful!")
            }
            else{
                switch policyError!.code{
                case LAError.SystemCancel.rawValue:
                    print("Authentication was cancelled by the system!")
                case LAError.UserCancel.rawValue:
                    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                        self.showPasswordAlert()

                    })
                    print("Authentication was cancelled by the user!")
                case LAError.UserFallback.rawValue:
                    print("User selected to enter password.")
                    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({() -> Void in
                        self.showPasswordAlert()
                    })
                default:
                    print("Authentication failed!")
                    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                        self.showPasswordAlert()
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
    else{
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
            self.showPasswordAlert()
        })
    }

var baseTableVC = BaseTableViewController()

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    let logInStatus = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let currentTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    let roundCurrentTime = (round(currentTime))
    // Pin expire limit
    let pinExpLimit: Double = 30
    // Set the exact time of expire for pin
    let pinExpDate = (currentTime + pinExpLimit)
    let newPinExpDate = (round(pinExpDate))
    if (logInStatus.doubleForKey("expPinTime") <= roundCurrentTime) {
        self.baseTableVC.authenticateUser()
        print("AppDelegate Pin Exp Time")
        print(logInStatus.doubleForKey("expPinTime"))
        //print(newPinExpDate)
        print("AppDelegate Current Time")
        print(roundCurrentTime)
        logInStatus.setDouble(newPinExpDate, forKey: "expPinTime")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    }
}
```

Comment: Does your authenticate method ever present a uialertcontroller?

Comment: Can you check the code that I added?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you simply create an instance of `BaseTableViewController` but you don't add its view to the view hierarchy before presenting the `UIAlertController`'s instance.

If `self.baseTableVC` is the root view controller of your app, then a call like this

```
baseTableVC.presentViewController(instanceOfUIAlertController, animated: true, completion: yourCompletionBlock)
```

should work from within the AppDelegate. 
If `self.baseTableVC` is not the root view controller, then or you make sure to invoke the previous command on the root VC of your app

```
window.rootViewController.presentViewController(instanceOfUIAlertController, animated: true, completion: yourCompletionBlock)
```

or make sure you embed the view of `self.baseTableVC` in the view hierarchy and then call

```
baseTableVC.presentViewController(instanceOfUIAlertController, animated: true, completion: yourCompletionBlock)
```

As a side note, if your alert must be displayed from anywhere in the app, then your approach is ok. If instead your alert must be displayed only from a specific screen, I would remove the timer logic from the app delegate and move it inside the presenting view controller. This would keep your app delegate clean from unnecessary code and would confine the control logic in the right place: the presenting view controller

Comment: Well the baseTableVC is not the root view controller but it is a super class to all my TableVC's. I have created the authenticateUser and showPasswordAlert inside of baseTableVC so I can call it. I want to be able to check when the user opens the app back up to see if they are still logged in with touch id. So I am trying to figure out where I should put the examples you gave me. Like I said I am pretty new to swift. Sorry but thank you for your input!

Comment: @Jeremie It would be helpful if you could post some code in your original question so I can understand better. Especially the code where you present the UIAlertController

Comment: The issue is still the one I mentioned you: at the moment you call `presentViewController:animate:completion` you must be sure that `self` has its view embedded in the view hierarchy.  The error message is very clear. You might want to read carefully the Apple Docs about view controllers https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/

Comment: I read about the view controllers but still not sure why or where I need to add the code.  I added my authenticateUser function to the question.  When I make the call to authenticateUser it works and if I use touch-id it works it is only when I cancel the touch-id to type in a password is when I get the error about the hierarchy?

Comment: Your code is not correctly formatted so I can't really say who's doing what. I see there appDelegate methods but also UIViewControllers methods. Could you perhaps put the important part of your code on github?

Comment: I haven't used git before so let me know if you can see this? https://github.com/golfjjhill/swift_touch-id.git

Comment: Do you use storyboard? Is `baseTableVC` part of the storyboard? If you put a break point at line 25 and print in the console `po baseTableVC.view.superview` what do you get? Is the code on github all the code you have? You are missing some closing curly brackets so I am afraid you omit part of the code which can help understand

Comment: I do use storyboards but baseTableVC is not part of the storyboard. After I printed what you said I got nil in the console.  I didn't include all the code for app delegate and all the code for basetableviewcontroller but I believe the only bracket that was missing was the closing bracket on the class. I can put on the code if that is what you need? Also I noticed that I had self.baseTableVC.presentViewController(self.baseTableVC.alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil) in app delegate but the alertVC was not in baseTableVC but it was just a trial and error thing.

Comment: I really think you should go and read the MVC pattern, especially about controllers and presenting views. If your controller is not part of a storyboard and you don't present its view from anywhere in your code, you will never be able to make it presenting an alert controller. Put your controller in a scene of your storyboard or present it programmatically before attempting any other alert presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create instance of view controller just by calling default constructor, use storyboard. Correct me if I'm wrong